# How do I query other Firebase Users?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I've updated to the newest Firebase (3.2) but can't figure out how to query other users. I've gotten their FacebookID from the Facebook SDK and want to pull data from Firebase based off of that.

I want to do something like below but need to do it on FIRUser instead.

```
let climbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("/climb")
let climbQuery = climbRef.queryOrderedByChild("userId").queryEqualToValue(userId)
```

Comment: Can you add (as text please, no screenshots) a snippet of the JSON structure under `/climb`? You can easily get this by exporting it from the Database tab in your Firebase Console.

Comment: I could but I'm actually not having trouble with the climb section (that was just an example). I'm trying to query users who aren't stored in the database section but rather in the authentication section.

Comment: There is no API to query users from Firebase Authentication.

Comment: So is the best way to do this store all of their data in the database as well to query? That seems awfully redundant.

Comment: That is the most common way that developers deal with being able to list/query user profiles. It's redundant. Whether that is awful is clearly subjective, because I often recommend duplication as a good way to enhance scalability.

Comment: Thanks for the help Frank!